# How can I test if a sequence is empty in F#?

Tags: f#

Consider this F# code which computes a factor of a number:

```
let n = 340339004337I

// A sequence of all factors:
let factors = seq { 1I .. n / 2I} |> Seq.filter (fun x -> n % x = 0I) 

// Pull off the first factor from the sequence:
let factor = 
    if factors = seq [] then
        n
    else
        factors |> Seq.nth 0
```

In other words, if `factors` is empty, then return `n`.  Otherwise, pull off the first element from `factors`.  The goal is to account for all factors between 1 and *(n/2)*, and *n* itself since 1 and *n* are always factors of *n*.

The `factors = seq []` test isn't working.  I arrived at this syntax by looking at this:

```
> seq {1 .. 100} |> Seq.filter (fun x -> false) ;;
val it : seq<int> = seq []
```

However, I don't think `seq []` is actually an empty sequence:

```
> Seq.empty = seq [] ;;
val it : bool = false
```

How can I test if a sequence is empty?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try [Seq.isEmpty](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee353547.aspx).

```
if Seq.isEmpty yourSeqName then doSomething else doSomethingElse
```

By the way, Seq.empty creates an empty Seq.  It doesn't test for one.

Comment: Thanks.  This was the first answer by a split second!

Answer (score 2):

Seq.isEmpty

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee353547.aspx

The problem with your `=` test, I presume, is that it is comparing two different objects of type `IEnumerable<int>` for reference-equality.

Comment: Thanks.  I looked at all the module functions for `Seq`, but wasn't careful enough.  I overlooked `Seq.isEmpty`.